# Starting stopping JBOSS jboss-eap-6.3.2 manually?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have JBOSS jboss-eap-6.3.2 installed, and I want to manually start/stop it. In bin directory I see the following script `standalone.sh`. There is no stop script in there.

How do I manually start / stop the JBOSS server?

One more things: does `standalone.sh` start the admin console of JBOSS as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standalone.sh starts everything.

If you started standalone.sh in interactive mode hit CTRL+C

More about starting and stopping you find in the documentation:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Start_and_Stop_JBoss_EAP_6.html